# How to handle users repeatedly posting comments as answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

How do we deal with users repeatedly posting answers instead of comments or updating their questions?

*Example:* [cinek1lol on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278074/cinek1lol):

- posted comments/clarifications as an answers on (as of now) all 3 questions
- was told that this doesn't match with SOs Q/A concept
- still did it again

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd simply vote these "answers" down so that they drop to the bottom of the page.

In severe cases you can also flag for moderator attention so that they can clean up the question and delete the useless "answers".

Answer (score 2):

He sounds more English language challenged than an aggressive rule breaker.

Comment: Than / then, what's the difference? :)

Comment: That is most likely correct, but doesn't help with him effectively *"spamming"* and completely not reacting to advice.

Answer (score 2):

Add a comment to explain to him what he's doing wrong; be polite, he might not know the rules around here. If he ignores your comment, **flag the answer** for moderator attention and move on. If enough people flag him, he'll lose 100 points; that should grab his attention...

Some people just don't seem to want to listen and learn anything. The best thing at times is to just flag and move on; don't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

I typically just grab the text in the 'answer' , move it to the original question, then replace the answer with something like this:

> Your additional information has been
>   automatically added as an addendum to
>   your original question. Note,
>   automatically does not infer a system
>   process, Jeff Atwood has me captive in
>   a warehouse with an automatic weapon
>   pointed at me, hence the term.
>
> If you continue to post updates to
>   your question as answers, he might
>   pull the trigger. Please help me live.

I am of course kidding. But the text is similar. Mostly, new users just 'get it' and delete the now edited 'answer'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that they have been dealt with appropriately so far, editing away the slightly desperate cries for help and so on.  Other than building in a mechanism to 'votekick' I don't see how it could have been handled better.

I reckon that [cinek1lol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278074/cinek1lol) will quickly get bored and move on.

Some facility to votekick user accounts would be counter to the SO community feel, IMO.

Comment: A votekick might be out of the question - but I'm sure a good waffle stamp on the forehead should do the trick. Honestly, he will probably judge the responses poor and move on. Darwin wins again.

Comment: mmmm waffles (on ponies).