# I have rep==1 and I can't comment on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, comments, meta

[EDIT] I see you reaching for that upvote button.  Don't do it!  If I get rep I won't be able to test the bug fix!  Oh wait, there's this nice community wiki checkbox to protect me in this situation. [/EDIT]

The FAQ says that (meta only) the requirement to be able to comment is only 1 rep.  Yet I can only comment on my own answers, not other people's questions and answers.

[image]

Comment: Clearly I can also comment on **my own** question.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the lack of a comment button on another post?

Comment: Snipping Tool, here I come.  I assume that I need an image hosting service to add graphics to SO questions?

Comment: @Ben: No, use the image button in the editing toolbar (between the code button and numbered list button) and you can upload right from here. Hopefully you're allowed to upload images with rep == 1! lol If you can only post a URL, we can edit it into an embedded image for you.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6919979/image%20impossible.PNG

Comment: I see you already caught on to the irony involved here :)

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6919979/add%20comment%20not%20found.PNG

Comment: I'm on it, fixing this now

Comment: @Ben, nice work there, especially the edit. Welcome to Meta, sir.

Comment: should be fixed now.

Comment: Tested, and I can confirm it is fixed (at least 21 rep is now enough to post comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I have good news for you, re associate your account with your SO account and you will get +100 therefore, you can ask comments.

<s>Potential Cause:</s>

They probably forgot to update the FAQ and make it 50 or something like that.

Comment: I could do that, but I couldn't test the bug fix ;)

Comment: @Ben: You need Jeff to fix it.

Comment: hence the "bug" tag

Comment: @thyrgle - +1 That helped me out as well.

Comment: @Ben: Exactly, you provided a bug, I provided a solution. :p. But, yeah, I understand what you're saying.

Comment: You provided a *workaround*.  There's a difference.

Comment: @Ben: I know. We're on a programming site remember? Every programmer knows there's a difference.

Comment: @thyrgle: I only wish.  Unfortunately some coders don't know the difference, and happily mark issues "solved" once they find a workaround (and the "fix" often is change the caller to stop passing in values that the function can't handle -- undocumented restriction of course -- instead of fixing the function to not crash the program when unexpected inputs are seen).