# Add "converted to comment" action to the moderator-action-list

Tags: feature-request, moderator-abilities

The ability to [convert an answer into a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments) was just added (woot!), and I've succesfully used it; it would be nice if an "answer was converted into a comment" message was added as a moderator action into a list of actions performed.

It's not very important, I admit, just nice. Will also give us all a feeling of how common this occurrence is.

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized what you meant by "moderator-action-list" compared to... what I figured you meant. Whoops. ♪ Knowing what you meant, I'm agreed to this.

Comment: I'm going to piggyback on this since I don't think it warrants its own feature request -- protecting a post should appear there too