# The 10k tools show no deleter for posts converted to comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, convert-to-comment

When a moderator converts a post into a comment, they are deleted with no owner information. This shows on the 10k tools as:

> Deleted yesterday by

Comment: It also isn't shown on the deleted post itself. The problem isn't just with the 10k tools. Perhaps that information isn't being stored anymore?

Comment: @Cody Well, at least there it says "Deleted yesterday", not "Deleted yesterday by"

Comment: True enough. The first time I saw that, I assumed that the OP had deleted it, rather than a moderator. I thought "how strange that I immediately flagged something and the OP thought to delete it". I liked it much better when the moderator was shown as responsible. +1 for the bug report.

Comment: Actually, it gets kinda messier than that. You should've seen one of Gaming's first convert to comments, eheheh... though it's a shame [you can't, because there's no record of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74231/add-converted-to-comment-action-to-the-moderator-action-list). If I recall correctly, I basically managed to impersonate Oak deleting the post *from the future*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next build we'll start saving/showing which moderator converted the post to a comment, e.g. "`Deleted by Nick Craver ♦`" will show up for future conversions.

Answer (score 5):

My proposal is that when an answer is converted to a comment, the system should automatically make a comment "on the mod's behalf" to put the comment it was converted to. Something like:

> Converted to Comment on post XXXX ~ drachenstern timestamp

So it's obvious which post it went to (you *could* even hyperlink it with markdown) and we know that the last action was "convert to comment" so it can be tracked easily.

Comment: +1 for cutting down on 'paperwork' :)

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this (and consequently, the [related issue of no traceability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74231/add-converted-to-comment-action-to-the-moderator-action-list)) is to *delete the post yourself first, then use convert-to-comment while it is deleted*.

This will reset the timestamp of your former deletion to match the event of the conversion. It doesn't address the issue that it won't display normally, but if you do this going forwards it will show up properly in the deleted list and other relevant histories.