# Answering comment-answered questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, answers-as-comments

This one is more of a netiquette question.

Sometimes I stumble on "unanswered" questions that were actually answered - in their comments.
Those questions are shown as unanswered in the statistics.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719699/composite-javascripts-in-c-asp-net-with-the-aspscriptmanager.

What should be done?

1. Flag the question so one moderator can somehow mark it as answered.
2. Answer the question yourself (as a community wiki answer), mostly by copying the comments.
3. Nothing. Move along.

**EDIT**

I'm talking about questions without activity for weeks or months.

**Feature request**

Give diamond-mods the ability to change a comment to an answer; and allow users to flag for this action.

Comment: My personal opinion is the same as @David. But since *1* isn't available I will do as @Gent and choose "*3 - Do nothing.*" because I don't want to attract down-voters.

Comment: FYI, the request at [Mark a comment as answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question) was declined.

Answer (score 5):

I think, of the three, I'd prefer the first as a more...well-mannered (?) option. The second seems the most likely to work, but even as a CW answer, it *feels* inherently rude to 'copy' somebody's answer.

Unfortunately, so far as I know, the diamond-mods have the ability to [change an 'answer' to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments), but not the reverse so far as I'm aware.

It's also worth noting that my personal bias is against the mis-leading statistics of an answered (even if only in comments) question being considered unanswered by the site's design/metrics.

Answer (score 2):

I would say if you intend on repeating what was already said, do nothing, the commenter has started a dialog with the OP and likely wanted to clarify the question before posting an answer to be assessed.

If you have something meaningful to ad beyond the information already included in the comment and you feel it answers the OP then please contribute.