# Reviewer deleted my comments and i do not think he have enough reason to do so

Tags: support, comments, review

I saw a question and I think I may also help by answering this question, and my account was banned then, why they have the rights to ban me and what can I do with it?
[image: I think it's correct to find out the meaning of that status code]

Comment: Your "comment" wasn't deleted. Your (poor) ***answer*** was ***converted*** to a comment -- which [is still there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195817/apigee-127-unable-to-deploy-to-on-premise-apigee-from-apigee-127-303-error#comment95004152_27195817).

Comment: Read [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) for deleted answer and [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) for answer ban.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should moderators be able to convert answers into comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments) (and others)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why and how are some answers deleted?

Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:

- **commentary on the question or other answers**
- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

Robert already wrote this **does not count as an answer**. Once you have [sufficient reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.