# Is it kosher to submit an answer, then edit it repeatedly?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

It irks me when I see a question on SO that I can answer, begin writing a detailed answer, and see that someone else answers with a one-liner.  Often, the other answerer will make many small edits to their answer, adding detail, so that even if I post my complete answer before they *really* finish theirs, it looks like I just copied their answer.

**Is the answer-then-edit-repeatedly strategy acceptable/encouraged** on Stack Overflow?  Should I stop letting it bother me and start doing it?

Comment: See [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88393/limit-on-editing-own-answers-different-type-of-edit-wars) linked question (or rather, then answers to it) help?

Comment: Delayed voting solution for FGW problem:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved

Comment: @DavidRobinson Exactly the question I was searching for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the quality of the original answer.  If it very clearly answers the question, and would be at least an acceptable answer, even if not a great one, when first posted, then it's not really a problem.  Turning an okay answer into a great answer still ensures that there isn't low quality content.

What's more of a problem is when people post an answer that doesn't actually answer the question as it stands, is missing key information, and is simply a placeholder to get an earlier timestamp.

In short, if you're inclined to upvote the answer based on the first revision, but the edit just made it that much better, I don't see it as a problem.  If it's a post you would downvote on the first revision but it's edited, and it was clearly posted with the *intent* of being edited right away, then I consider this abusing the system and am generally disinclined to remove my initial downvote.

Comment: And if they do the second then downvote them.