# What triggers the "possible rollback war" flag?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks, rollback-wars

Just saw this one for the first time:

> **1 × rollback war**

(for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217484/how-do-i-call-a-stored-procedure-with-unconventional-parameters)'s [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9217484/revisions))

Its obvious what this flag means (multiple rollbacks have occurred, possibly by different users), but what exactly are the conditions under which this flag appears?

Additionally, what action could/should be taken on this flag?

I see [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75906/put-an-end-to-rollback-wars#) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3600/153691) (heck, there's a whole [rollback-wars](/questions/tagged/rollback-wars) tag), but there isn't any indication as to how the feature was actually implemented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the question you linked, two rollbacks by the same user triggered the flag.

Moderator action is taken if, when the moderator reviews the edit history, it is apparent that two or more users are engaged in repeated rollbacks in an attempt to claim their own edited version of the post.

Moderator action can include an additional roll-back to the version the moderator deems the best one, locking the post for a short time to prevent further rollbacks, and suspension of users if the behavior is especially egregious or disruptive.

Rollback wars most commonly occur when a new user doesn't understand [this part of the faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing), or someone is changing the meaning of a post.

Comment: So to be clear, we leave Rollback War flags to the mods?  Because I came across one while reviewing flags this afternoon.  I wasn't sure what if anything I ought to do about this flagged question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/17345995/146325

Comment: @APC: Only mods can lock a post to stop a rollback war, so I'm not sure what a Trusted User can do, other than to make certain observations about the post nad the most desirable edit state.  That question looks OK, though.  The OP elected to defer to the second revision.

Comment: Okay.  It's just in the third revision they added some clarification; then somebody rewrote the question to make the clarification the main body of the question and re-titled it.  The OP bridled at that, which is their perogative, but I think they should have rolled back to revision #3 and kept the clarification.