# User keeps rollbacking correct edits

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I do a lot of edits on question when I think I can improve them significantly (I hate minor edits).

But I got a user who doesn't seem to understant the edit policy on SO and he keeps rollbacking my edit. I already posted a comment which links to `[faq#editing]`.

The question is: [Twig/Symfony2 extension of path/url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673998/twig-symfony2-extension-of-path-url)

**What can I do to stop this 'rollback dance'?**

A possible option I got from [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75906/put-an-end-to-rollback-wars) is to flag it for a moderator, but what can he do about it? Is there a real solution for this or should I just stop rollbacking and leave the post worse formatted?

Comment: ChrisF has rolled back. Perhaps it stops now.

Comment: Is it bad that I want to roll it back again just for the lulz?

Comment: PS, I won't actually do that.

Comment: It possible he sees it as *his* question, and doesn't like changes that would influence the way he thinks it *should* look/sound/etc. I know I tend to write my questions the way I lay it out in my head or in a manner that reflects how I think or speak, so I don't always approve of edits which cause my question to no longer sound right when I read *my* question in *my* head. Of course, the post is typically improved by the edits so I let it go. He might disapprove more strongly. Just my thoughts.

Comment: A mod can lock the post, which prevents edits, comments, and votes.

Comment: @Wouter - You can also look at it from the other side: If the OP doesn't appreciate your edits, that's his problem. Just leave him with his mediocre(?) post.

Comment: @BoPersson but I don't see posts as ownership of the poster, they belong to SO and all users should do their best to improve all content of SO.

Comment: @Wouter - But rather, if he doesn't appreciate your help with the question, please go help someone else. There is no lack of posts that need improvement.

Comment: Looks like they reverted to their original question *again* after ChrisF rolled the edits back and instructed the user not to do it again. So I rolled back to the latest edits, and they deleted the question entirely. So there you have it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You step away from the question. Do not get into a rollback war, certainly not over a few formatting improvements. Post a comment instead, which you did.

If there is a bigger problem (OP is destroying posts, repeated vandalism, etc.) you can flag the post for moderator attention. Moderators can lock a post for a limited time if warranted.

There is an automatic [rollback war flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121948/what-triggers-the-possible-rollback-war-flag) trigger when multiple rollbacks happen, so the post in question may already *be* flagged for mod attention.

Comment: Stack Overflow is so bad(expletive). There's a rollback war flag trigger...awesome.